# HERE iOS and Swift 3 - works or breaks?

Tags: swift3, here-api

I am currently running Xcode 7 on my Mac which is running on MacOS 10.3.

I just started a chain of events that I hope ends well.... I upgraded my iPhone from iOS 9 to iOS 10. Now when i try to compile my app to the phone through Xcode I'm getting a warning from Xcode "cannot find developer disk image" which means I have to upgrade Xcode 7 to Xcode 8 (which in turn I hope will work on my computer). 
My question is: will the HERE iOS SDK work with Xcode 8? Xcode 8 contains swift 3!

Answer (score 1):

Our upcoming release will properly support XCode 8. Please wait until it is release. (Current release is 3.2.1, next release will be 3.2.2)

Comment: That is interesting @David because HERE emailed me 2 days after your answer that version 3.2 is compatible, making no difference between 3.2.1 & 3.2.2. Here is a direct quote: "Our 3.2.x version of the HERE iOS Mobile SDK should be compatible with your upgrade as well as Swift 3."

Comment: We have not tested 3.2.1 with XCode 8, 3.2.2 is the first release that will be supported and fully tested with XCode 8